# How to unit test gutenberg class/component method that uses wp.apiFetch

Tags: wordpress, jestjs, wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to unit test a method on a class/component that calls the wp.apiFetch method but when I run the test it always says `TypeError: apiFetch is not a function` the below structure has worked for other test cases, all be it they don't make any api calls.

**Stripped down test setup**

```
global.wp = {};
// some other packages
Object.defineProperty(global.wp, 'apiFetch', { get: () => require('@wordpress/api-fetch') });
```

**Stripped down test**

1. Shallow render the component
2. Call the method in question on the component instance - at this point here the tests error because of the error mentioned at the top.
3. Check that the method was called

```
  it('createAuthor valid', () => {
    // may have to mock window.fetch as wp.apiFetch uses it but that's currently not the issue

    const componentProps = {
      someFunc: jest.fn(),
    };

    const component = shallow(<NewAuthor {...componentProps} />);
    component.setState({ name: 'john smith' });

    component.instance().createAuthor();

    expect(componentProps.someFunc).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

**Stripped down component**

```
const { apiFetch } = wp;
// some more constants from window

class NewAuthor extends Component {
  // constructor
  // method to test
  createAuthor = () => {
    const { someFunc, someErrorFunc } = this.props;
    const authorObject = {
      name,
    } = this.state;
    const createPath = '/wp/v2/users';

    apiFetch({
      path: createPath,
      data: authorObject,
      method: 'POST',
    })
      .then((user) => {
        console.log('success', user);
        someFunc();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error', error);
        someErrorFunc();
      });
  };
  // some more methods
  // render
}

export default NewAuthor;
```